# What caused the toast with "Call failed, try another method"?

Tags: calls, 7.0-nougat, apn, toast-notifications, motorola-moto-g-4g-plus

I am having an issue with my Motorola G4 Plus smartphone which runs on Android 7.0 version. I am using JIO SIM card for calls and internet.

Two days ago, my phone showed me a toast message stating:

> Call failed, try another method.

I was not able to initiate or receive any calls. Meanwhile my internet was working fine.

I searched about the toast message on internet and found some tricks to tackle the problem. Some of the major tricks were as follows:

- some suggested to clear the cache memory of the device.
- some suggested to change the network settings and reboot the device.
- some suggested to change the specific APN settings and than to restart the device.
- some suggested to change the set recommended 4G LTE settings.

I tried all of the above tricks but no gain at last.

**My main question is**: which method was the toast message referring to?
 Or, by saying "*try another method*" which method do I have to concern about and how to eventually solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue before. An answer on Quora solved it.

Remove your Jio sim without switching off the device and insert another network different from Jio into the sim1 slot.

Switch off your phone and switch it back on.

Put your jio sim into the sim2 slot. Now restart your phone.

I hope it works for you.

Comment: yeah thanks. Now I am able to make call and receive as well. Your trick worked but your answer is half. Still the other portion remain which is regarding the 'try another method' toast message. Which method is the toast referring?? please edit your answer.

Comment: It worked for me.